# Compile shared object library, which call function from so too

Tags: c++, g++, shared-libraries

I have got a f2.cpp file

```
// f2.cpp
#include <iostream>

void f2()
{
    std::cout << "It's a call of f2 function" << std::endl;
}
```

I use cygwin with crosstool compiler gcc.

```
g++ -fPIC -c f2.cpp
g++ -shared -o libf2.so f2.o
```

I have got a libf2.so file. Now I want to call f2 function in f1 library (shared object too) libf1.so.

It's a f1.cpp and i want take f1.so

```
// f1.cpp
#include <iostream>
void f1()
{
    std::cout << "f1 function is calling f2()..." << std::endl;
    f2();
}
```

How i must compile f1.cpp? I don't want to use dlclose, dlerror, dlopen, dlsym...
Аt last i want to use f1.so in main.cpp as a shared object library too... without using use dlclose, dlerror, dlopen, dlsym. How I must compile main.cpp, when i will have a f1.so ?

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    f1();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

declare f2() in a header file. and compile libf1.so similar to libf2.

Now compile main linking against f1 and f2. 
It should look something like this
`g++ -lf2 -lf1 -L /path/to/libs main.o`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply link them together (if `f2` is compiled into `libf2.so`, you pass `-lf2` to the linker). The linker will take care of connecting calls from `f1` to `f2`. Naturally, *at runtime* `f1` will expect to find `f2` in the SO load path and the dynamic loader will load it.

Here's a more complete sample, taken from a portion of a Makefile I found lying around. Here, `mylib` stands for your `f2`, and `main_linked` is `f1`:

```
mylib: mylib.c mylib.h
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -fpic -c mylib.c
    gcc -shared -o libmylib.so mylib.o

main_linked: main_linked.c mylib.h mylib.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -L. -lmylib main_linked.c -o main_linked
```

Note:

1. `mylib` is compiled into a shared library with `-shared`
2. `main_linked` is then built with a single `gcc` call passing `-lmylib` to specify the library to link and `-L.` to say where to find it (in this case - current dir)

Answer (score 1):

Check the -L and -l flags to g++.